# An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request.

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to setup an asp.net website in localhost. Fitst, I  enabled IIS server and created website in 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder and ran to ensure IIS is properly setup. In this case I used a existing website I created from visualstudio IDE. Everything was perfect. In this case I heavily used the following article.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1689133.aspx

Now the problem is I have a web site I downloaded from a remoteserver and I want to host it in localhost.
When I compare the site I downloaded and the working site, I noticed that some files are missing. Howevere, the site in remote sever is working properly.

I didnt see a bin folder and there is no much information on web.config file.

Here is the code in web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I try to do the same process I did for the previous website and tried the browser then I get following erro.

```
Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL. 

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
```

Where is the error ? How to fix this issue? If you want more information let me know?

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you to first allow all users in WebConfig

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>    
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>    
</system.web>
```

**EDIT** : As Mentionned by [David Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265372/1379243), this is highly insecure. Use this only to unblock your test sample code scenario. Never in Production, please.

Comment: Can you explain that how to alllow for all users

Comment: This really ticked me off. I got stuck looking for this in IIS, under Authorization Rules. Everything there looked OK. As soon as I made this change in the Web.Config, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please keep in mind this is highly insecure as mentionned by David Thomson. Should be used only to quick start sample scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but the answer is seriously insecure, you should add and enable the authentication provider that you require rather than giving *anyone* authorization.

To add the provider:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers/add

To enable the method:

1. Open the IIS Management Console on the web server
2. Expand the Sites folder
3. Double-Click the IIS - Authentication option
4. Under Authentication, select the Anonymous Authentication and click 'Disable' in the Actions pane on the right
5. For Windows Authentication: Select the Windows Authentication and click 'Enable' in the Actions pane on the right
6. For Basic Authentication: Select the Basic Authentication and click 'Enable' in the Actions pane on the right

Comment: My issue was the Anon Authentication rather than using the windows authentication. Hopefully OP got it working as well.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for my was enabling 32-bit applications in the app pool's advanced settings.

1. Open IIS
2. Expand server and click `Application Pools` in the `Connections` pane
3. Select your application pool and click `Advanced Settings...`
4. Under `General` switch `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `True`